# Report Lab can't handle hebrew (unicode)

Tags: python, reportlab, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to generate the pdf from following python programming but generated output doesn't display hebrew letters correctly

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
def hello(c):
    c.drawString(100,100, "מה שלומך")
c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf")
hello(c)
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the font with `setFont` before `drawString`?

Comment: I didn't get which font type I should set

Answer (score 11):

This code (see below) works! All you need to do is place `ArialHB.ttf` (or any other font that supports Hebrew characters) into `site-packages/reportlab/fonts`...

The desired output will be at the bottom of the pdf page.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas 
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics 
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont 

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Hebrew', 'ArialHB.ttf'))

def hello(c):
    c.setFont("Hebrew", 14)
    c.drawString(10,10, u"מה שלומך".encode('utf-8'))

c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf") 
hello(c) 
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the proper decode call like `"מה שלומך".decode("utf-8")` it works.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
def hello(c):
    c.drawString(100,100, "מה שלומך".decode("utf-8"))
c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf")
hello(c)
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Comment: Or, more simply, use `u"מה שלומך"`.

Comment: Hrm, Reportlab states that both `unicode` and `utf-8` encoded strings are supported, so this cannot be the answer. See the [PDF userguide](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf), page 41, section 3.1.

Comment: My experience has been that ReportLab flubs on Unicode and you need to use UTF-8.  I've had many problems with non-ASCII characters solved just by making sure everything is UTF-8.

Comment: above solution doesn't work for me. I have already tried these permutation and combinations.