# Python Reportlab - Unable to print special characters

Tags: python, reportlab

`Python Reportlab`:

I am facing problem while printing special characters in my `pdf` like `"&"`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

def myFirstPage(canvas, doc):
  canvas.saveState()

def go():
  doc = SimpleDocTemplate("phello.pdf")
  Story = [Spacer(1,2*inch)]
  Story.append(Paragraph("Some text", styles["Normal"]))
  Story.append(Paragraph("Some other text with &", styles["Normal"]))
  doc.build(Story, onFirstPage=myFirstPage) 

go()
```

I Expected following output

```
 Some text
 Some other text with &
```

But the output I get is

```
 Some text
 Some other text with
```

Where did '&' get vanished.

I have searched some forums which say that I need to encode it as `&amp;` but is there not easier way to handle this than encoding each special character?

I have added `"# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-"` at the top of my script but that does not solve my problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Report Lab can't handle hebrew (unicode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958904/report-lab-cant-handle-hebrew-unicode)

Comment: No sdasdadas. That solution given in that thread does not solve my problem

Answer (score 6):

You should replace &, < and > with the `&amp;`, `&lt;` and `&gt;`. One easy way to do that is the Python escape function:

```
from cgi import escape
Story.append(Paragraph(escape("Some other text with &"), styles["Normal"]))
```

However, HTML tags need to have real < and > so a typical use would be more like:

```
text = "Some other text with &"
Story.append(Paragraph(escape("<b>" + text + "</b>"), styles["Normal"]))
```